# Edit tab selected by default

Tags: sitecore-client

When I click on an item in the Sitecore tree, the right hand pane has an `Edit` tab displayed by default, rather than the `Content` tab.

In the past when we didn't have this problem, we'd be able to click on items with the same template, editing a single field in each of the items, and the `Content` tab would be open by default, and the right hand pane would be scrolled to the field that was being edited in the previously selected item. We'd like to have that behaviour back.

I'm not sure when this behaviour disappeared, and it may have been after an upgrade or migration of content to a new platform.

I've checked the Standard Values of some of these items - I clicked on Configure > Editors and they do have an `Edit` option. I just can't see how to make the `Content` tab appear before `Edit` (or if that's even possible).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the editor tabs can be controlled by switching to the Core database in desktop mode. Navigate to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors` and find the definition item for your tab among its descendants. Edit the `Tab Sort Order` field to control where it appears.

The Content tab is hard-coded with sort order 100. The special search tab with the magnifying glass icon is defined by the item at `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Editors/Items/New Search` -
 `{4C76D96D-3343-404A-834B-0DC4DABB5EE3}`.

The tabs are sorted from left to right, so if you set the Tab Sort Order for a custom tab to 100 or less, it will appear to the left of the Content tab. If you set it to a value greater than 100, it will appear to the right of the Content tab. If two custom tabs have the same sort order, then the order in which they are selected in the Editors field is also taken into account.

Regardless of the order of the tabs, Sitecore should remember which tab you last had open when you are navigating between items. So if you are viewing the Content tab on one item and then select another item, it should keep the Content tab open on the new item.

Comment: Just a note before I make any changes: I have items named "A" and "B" in my content tree, sitting at the same level, and inheriting from the same template. I clicked on "A", and it defaulted to the `Edit` tab. I click on the `Content` tab. When I click on "B" after doing this, it opened with the `Edit` tab open. When I clicked on "A" again, it opened on the `Content` tab.

Comment: It seems the editor remembers the position, but doesn't remember the tab - it always opens the first tab for any item. Having said that, changing the sort order addressed my issue. Thanks!